# Determine family, $\mathcal{F}$ = sequence of $f_{n}(x)$ that are $C_{n}$ - Lipschitz and $C_{n} \to C$ in $[0,1]$ is compact - Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

Determine if the family, $\mathcal{F}$ = sequence of  $f_{n}(x)$ that are $C_{n}$ - Lipschitz and $C_{n} \to C$ in $[0,1]$ is compact.

To determine if this set of functions is compact we have to establish the set is:

- bounded
- closed
- equicontinuous

**Proof:**

**i)** Equicontinuity:

It is known that all Lipschitz functions are continuous. In this case let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{C_{n}}$:

$$\therefore |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(y)| \leq C_{n}|x-y| < C_{n} \frac{\epsilon}{C_{n}} = \epsilon$$

So $\mathcal{F}$ is actually uniformly equicontinuous.

**ii)** Bounded:  (I am having some troubles with this and the next)

*Want to show:* $\exists M > 0$ such that $|f_{n}| \leq M$, for all $f_{n} \in \mathcal{F}$ on $[0,1]$

Since these functions are Lipschitz:

$$ |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(y)| \leq C_{n}|x-y|$$

Now I was thinking since I am on $[0,1]$ I could perhpas do something like let $x = 0, y = 1$. Then that would mean:

$$ |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(y)| \leq C_{n}$$

I feel that I should be able to get some sort of bound from this, but perhaps I am writing something wrong in terms of my interpretation.

**iii)** Closed

*Want to show:* $f \in \mathcal{F}$, which is the same as $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|$

Suppose that $f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly to $f$.  This means that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $N > 0$ such that $|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, for all $n \geq N$ and $x,y \in [0,1]$.

Putting this together: $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f_{n}(x)| + |f_{n}(x) - f_{n}(y)| + |f_{n}(y) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3} + C_{n}|x-y| + \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$

Again I am having som eissues with the final statement. I envisioned something of the sort $C_{n}|x-y|$ appearing in all of my terms and then taking $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, but it didn't work out how I had hoped.

Comment: Suppose $f_n(X)=n$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and all $n$.  Is this set of functions compact?

Comment: on inspection it does look equicontinuous, I don't think it is bounded though because  $n$ can go to $\infty$ and as such no bound exists......Are you implying that's what could happen with my Lipschitz constant?

Comment: These $f_n$ are all uniformly Lipschitz (with $C_n=0$) and thus the set is equicontinuous.  The $f_n$ clearly do not converge.  As you say, boundedness is what goes wrong here.

Comment: You have been posting  many problems about compactness of a  family of fuctions. Compactness is w.r.t. a given topology and you cannot talk about compactness without specifying the topology/metric/norm you are using. I believe I already mentioned this earlier but you keep repeating the same mistake. I have given you a downvote for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for your honest feedback @KaviRamaMurthy. What mistake do you see from me that I am repeating?  Is it not stating what the topology /norm that I am working on?

Comment: Your question is about compactness of $(f_n)$ **in** $C[0,1]$ **with the sup metric**. You should always mention  the space and the norm.